# iOS: Animating Multiple UIBezierPaths (One After the Other)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, cashapelayer, caanimation

I have an array of `UIBezierPaths`, but I'm having trouble doing so.

I've tried calculating the beginTime by doing the following, but all it does is animate the first line, but not the rest of the lines (they just appear without an animation).

```
pathAnimation.beginTime = n * lineDuration;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pathAnimation.beginTime = n * lineDuration;
```

Well, that's your problem. That time is in the deep dark past.

You want a time in the *future*. Start by getting the `CACurrentMediaTime()` and now *add* the delay amount to that.

Comment: Awesome thanks Matt. That definitely did the track. Only one minor issue. If I have 5 lines, line 1 draws itself, but all 5 lines show up, then line 2 draws itself, etc. How do I keep the lines from showing until it's time to animate them?

Comment: I've figured it out using an opacity animation! Thanks though